# Can not hit controller method while submitting ajax form using jQuery in Spring-Boot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

Can not hit controller method while submitting ajax form using jQuery in Spring-Boot.

Below is my html code :

```html
<div class="main-container">
 <div class="col-md-6 offset-3" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <form th:object="${user}" method="post" id="registration_form">
   <div class="form-group">
    <small>Full Name</small>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <small>Email</small>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" />
   </div>    
   <div class="form-group">
    <small>Password</small> 
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" />
   </div>
  </form>    
  <div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
    <button id="btn_cancle" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="clear_reg_form()" style="width:100px;">Clear</button>
    <button id="btn_save" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit_reg_form()" style="width:100px;">Save</button>
   </div>     
  </div>   
 </div>
</div>
```

Below is my jQuery code :

```js
$.ajax({
 url: "/register",
 type: 'POST',
 data: $('#registration_form').serialize(),
 success: function(data) {
  $("#loader").hide();
  var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  if(data.is_error == "false"){
   $("#msg_div").text(data.message);
  } else if(data.is_error == "true"){
   $("#msg_div").text(data.message);
  }
  $("#btn_cancle").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("#btn_save").removeAttr("disabled");
 },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
  $("#msg_div").html(jqXHR.responseText);
  console.log("ERROR : ", jqXHR.responseText);
  
  $("#btn_save_document_link").removeAttr("disabled");
 }
});
```

And here is my function in controller :

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public HashMap<String, String> saveUser(@Valid User user) {
    System.out.println("In registra controller -->>>");

    HashMap<String, String> returnMap = new HashMap<>();

    if(userService.isEmailExists(user.getEmail())) {
        returnMap.put("message", messagesService.emailExists);
    } else if(user.getPassword() == "" || user.getPassword().length() < 5) {
        returnMap.put("message", messagesService.passwordLength);
    } else {
        returnMap.put("message", "success");
        userService.createUser(user);
    }

    return returnMap;
}
```

But while click on Submit button; it shows below message :
[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your request is not allowed, it receives the status `403 - FORBIDDEN`. Do you use spring security ? Don't you need to include the csrf token ?

Comment: No I did not include the csrf token.

Comment: Can you show error from server side? And can you show your pom.xml or check if there is no "spring security" dependency